# Should I use the present simple or present continuous here?

Tags: tenses, present-tense, continuous-aspect

Which of these two paragraphs is correct?

The first paragraph:

> Secondly, the author gives an example about meerkats. He argues that the sentinel meerkat guards his group **while they are eating or searching for food**...

The second paragraph:

> Secondly, the author gives an example about meerkats. He argues that the sentinel meerkat guards his group **while they eat or search for food**.

Are they both correct?

Comment: I think they're both acceptable with essentially the same meaning.

Comment: It would be incorrect to use "are eating", as the sentinel meerkat "guards"--the sentence does not say he "is guarding." Keep consistent tense.

Answer (score -1):

I feel both paragraphs are right,the first pagraph can be right in given contexts. Eg:Say that a story is written about a family of meerkats,it would be,'the sentinel gaurds his group while they are eating or searching for food' .In a general context, however, such as in an encyclopedia, the second paragraph is right.